# Creating a new column in my data frame labelling single and multiple encounters

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have some whale watching ecotourism data that looks like this:

```
Id     Date        Time     Day Encounter
A1     20110527    10:42    1   1
A1     20110527    11:24    1   2
A1     20110527    11:52    1   3
A1     20110603    10:29    2   4
A1     20110603    10:59    2   5
A1     20110603    13:26    2   6
A1     20120708    11:32    3   7
A3     20110503    11:05    1   1
A3     20110503    11:23    1   2
A3     20110503    11:45    1   3
A3     20110503    12:05    1   4
A3     20110503    12:17    1   5
A3     20110622    13:06    2   6
A3     20110622    13:15    2   7
```

Where `Id` is the whale ID, `Date` is the date of encounter, `Day` is the number of days encountered and `Encounter` is the number of encounters.

I would like to create a new column that specifies whether an individual was encountered on only one day or on multiple days. I have been playing around with the `[.data.table()` call but am not having much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably `DT[, seen_mult := uniqueN(Date) > 1L, by=Id]`. I'd suggest looking at the vignettes for the package to get an idea for its syntax: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: A `dplyr` equivalent: `df %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(is_multi_day = length(unique(Date)) > 1)`

Comment: @alistaire The dplyr equivalent to uniqueN is n_distinct, fyi. Still, I'm not even sure if this is what the op was looking for, since there's no desired output here.

Comment: @Frank Curious, somehow I've never used that before. And yeah, a MRE is not very useful when the whole column comes out to `TRUE`.